# Differences between IFn and Fn in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

I couldn't understand differences between IFn and fn.

Could you give examples too?

Please provide differences between those functions:

```
(fn? x)

(ifn? x)
```

they behave like same.

Comment: Provide us your understanding of `IFn` and `fn` and what is not clear for you so we know what needs clarification.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl (fn? x) and (ifn? x) functions behave identical (approximately)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clojure docs describes the difference quite clearly:

> [`(fn? x)`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn_q)
>   Returns true if x implements Fn, i.e. is an object created via fn.
>
> [`(ifn? x)`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ifn_q)
>   Returns true if x implements IFn. Note that many data structures
>   (e.g. sets and maps) implement IFn

You can test it:

```
(fn? (fn [] nil)) ;; => true
(fn? #{}) ;; => false
(fn? {}) ;; => false
(fn? []) ;; => false
(fn? :a) ;; => false
(fn? 'a) ;; => false

(ifn? (fn [] nil)) ;; => true
(ifn? #{}) ;; => true
(ifn? {}) ;; => true
(ifn? []) ;; => true
(ifn? :a) ;; => true
(ifn? 'a) ;; => true
```

In other words `fn?` says if its argument is an object which is just and only a function (created with `(fn ...)`), `ifn?` says if an object is a thing which can be called like a function (even if it wasn't created with `(fn ...)`).

Comment: Note that `IFn` is a proper interface, characterised by many `apply` methods. But `Fn` is an empty interface: it can be attached to any class as a kind of tag.